# How to put (static) content in a right column on each page in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

i want to create a template for Libreoffice Writer which contains a right column for informations which should be displayed on all pages.
In fact i want a kind of page header on the right side.

Is there any way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a text frame that's anchored in the header / footer. This way, you can place content on the same place on every page while that content doesn't need to keep inside the header / footer margins.

To do so, just activate header or footer, place the cursor inside it and select Menu `Insert` -> `Frame`. To keep the main page content apart from the "right column", just set the right page margin appropriately.

If the content that should appear in the "right column" is non-textual, you could also try to implement it as background image of the header / footer. AFAIK background images in header / footer aren't restricted to the header / footer area.

Comment: Thanks. Never thought about that :)